# How to keep two separate UV maps when merging two objects into one?

Tags: texturing, uv, objects

I wondered how to keep two UV separate UV maps when merging two objects into one (<kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)?
Currently I have blender 2.80.

I have two separate objects (in this case a turtle and a catapult from a game).
I would like to merge them both and let each keep it's own UV map.
In blender this seems alright before merging. However, after merging they
are converted into 1 wrong UV map. The turtle's UV map is degraded into a single pixel in the lower left of the UV map, resulting in a mono-colored animal.
The catapult has it's texture from in game, so I cannot supply it (but you can see it in the object).

Link for Blender file with objects:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jvj2oafghnmll57/CataToSend.blend?dl=0
Link for JPEG turtle texture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9a5yiftua1v1jek/20446_Sea_Turtle_diff.jpg.001.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On each object, prior to merging, give it an additional UV map with the name of the other object's UV map.  After merging the objects, it will merge these individual UV maps.  Although note that when you create an additional UV map, it will have the same UV values as the selected UV map, so you might want to do whatever you want to these-- there's no such thing as being unmapped in some map, that just means UV 0,0.

Comment: Much thanks for your answer, this indeed did fix the issue. I gave each UV map the same name before merging (to change the name -> select the Context (object data = small green upside down triangle in one of the side bars) -> UV Maps -> edit names). This resulted in being able to use the ideal texture for each object.